# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report! - Nov 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, monthly

## Welcome Our SharePoint Stack Exchange Valued Contributors.

We would like to share with you the **Most Active Contributors Report** over the last month!

[image]

**This report includes the following awards:**

1. Monthly Leader Board.
2. Most Active Contributors Award.
3. Most Active Editors Award.
4. Most Active Voters Award.
5. Most Close Votes Review Award.
6. Most First Post Review Award.
7. Most Late Answer Review Award.
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.
9. Most Reopen Review Award.
10. Most Suggested Edit Review Award.
11. Highest Votes Questions Award.
12. Highest Votes Answers Award.
13. Most Viewed Questions Award.
14. 1st Top Contributors summary list.

---

[image]

[image]

You can find the full list at [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/month/sharepoint/2017-11-02)

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                   REPUTATION
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                   1,078
2   Waqas Sarwar MVP           585
3   Gautam Sheth               525
4   Vainktesh Kumar            400
5   Amy_MSFT                   320
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                    EDITS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                   70
2   Waqas Sarwar MVP           23
3   Mike                       20
4   Tally                      18
5   Gaurravs                   18
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     VOTES
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Crazy Ivan                  196
2   Martin Tyler                71
3   Asad Refai                  67
4   P S                         53
5   Archiver SP                 46
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                     24
2   M.Qassas                     16
3   Gaurravs                     14
4   moe                          9
5   Gautam Sheth                 9
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                     95
2   M.Qassas                     47
3   Zach Koehne                  31
4   P S                          30
5   Ram                          28
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                    32
2   Waqas Sarwar MVP            17
3   M.Qassas                    16
4   Ram                         11
5   Zach Koehne                 6
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                    30
2   Asad Refai                  27
3   M.Qassas                    24
4   P S                         21
5   moe                         11
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                     7
2   Asad Refai                   6
3   M.Qassas                     6
4   moe                          4
5   Dikesh Gandhi                4
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                     39
2   M.Qassas                     31
3   Waqas Sarwar MVP             21
4   P S                          12
5   Dikesh Gandhi                10
```

---

[image]

1. [Clear list items and reset id back to 1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230338/clear-list-items-and-reset-id-back-to-1)

   - **Quest Owner:** Chicago.
   - **Votes:** 7.
2. [What happens if SharePoint timer service stops?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231969/what-happens-if-sharepoint-timer-service-stops)

   - **Quest Owner:** Kishore.
   - **Votes:** 4.
3. [SharePoint 2013 too many content databases](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231271/sharepoint-2013-too-many-content-databases)

   - **Quest Owner:** user57156.
   - **Votes:** 4.

---

[image]

1. [Hide/Show columns in Custom List based on dropdown Selection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231642/hide-show-columns-in-custom-list-based-on-dropdown-delection/231652#231652)

   - **Answer Owner:** M.Qassas.
   - **Votes:** 6.
2. [Create Modern Sites in SharePoint Online using CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230490/create-modern-sites-in-sharepoint-online-using-csom/230494#230494)

   - **Answer Owner:** Gautam Sheth.
   - **Votes:** 6.
3. [Clear list items and reset id back to 1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230338/clear-list-items-and-reset-id-back-to-1/230339#230339)

   - **Answer Owner:** Per Jakobsen.
   - **Votes:** 6.

---

[image]

1. [SharePoint Online, how to change Group site name?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231660/sharepoint-online-how-to-change-group-site-name)

   - **Views:** 603.
2. [Create Modern Sites in SharePoint Online using CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230490/create-modern-sites-in-sharepoint-online-using-csom)

   - **Views:** 328.
3. [Clear list items and reset id back to 1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230338/clear-list-items-and-reset-id-back-to-1)

   - **Views:** 288.

---

[image]

1. **Most Active Contributors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
2. **Most Active Editors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
3. **Most Active Voters Award.**

   - [Crazy Ivan](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/34941/crazy-ivan)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
4. **Most Close Votes Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
5. **Most First Post Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
6. **Most Late Answer Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
7. **Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
8. **Most Reopen Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
9. **Most Suggested Edit Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
10. **Highest Votes Questions Award.**

    - [Chicago](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/71553/chicago) Great Question, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
11. **Highest Votes Answers Award.**

    - [Gautam Sheth](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/8068/gautam-sheth) Great Answer, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
    - [Per Jakobsen](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/990/per-jakobsen) Great Answer, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
    - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Answer, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
12. **Most Viewed Questions Award.**

    - [SharePoint Online, how to change Group site name?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231660/sharepoint-online-how-to-change-group-site-name)

---

Thank you so much all contributors for volunteering, We fully appreciate all the great contributions of all valuable SharePoint StackExchange members.

> **P.S.:** This report will be published Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback & precious suggestion!

Comment: As usual, awesome job ! For December 2017, could you also please create a yearly stats report  (if its possible, separate from the monthly report, and not too much trouble :P )  ? Keep up the good work, cheers !!!

Comment: Sure, bro, I will publish it ASAP